# how to keep double quotes in twig?

Tags: javascript, php, json, symfony, twig

I have a json array that I pass to the twig template, but the double quotes in the array have been causing trouble, my json array is like this:

```
$arr = json_encode(array("a", "b")); // which prints out ["a", "b"]
```

in twig template, I print it out like this:

```
attrs: {{ arr }}
```

I expect it to be `attrs: ["a", "b"]`, however, what gets output is `attrs: [&quot;a&quot;, &quot;b&quot;]`, I tried `attrs: {{ arr|e('js') }}`, but no luck, my js lib just says there are some unrecognised characters. So how do I get intended `attrs: ["a", "b"]`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sounds like you have auto-escaping on. (e: which is a good thing)

Have you tried `{{ arr|raw }}` ?

Comment: "raw" to the rescue! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can be use [`escape`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/escape.html) filter from twig for display double quotes into javascript.

```
{{ array|json_encode|raw|escape('js') }}
```